# Linux to Windows repository pull and push

Tags: linux, git, repository, git-push, git-pull

Our entire code base at work is housed on an IIS Windows environment. My task was to
copy the code to our new Linux Ubuntu server and go through the code to make the changes necessary to get it to run on the Linux box. It took a couple months but it works. In the meantime, code updates were made on the productions Windows server to the code base by another developer. Now I have the task of pushing the changes to the Linux box so we can pull the trigger and run it live in the new environment.

PROBLEM:

When I performed a `git push origin master` I was thrown an error stating that I must perform a `pull` first. Upon diverging and running a `git status` it says I have `11 and 3 commits each, respectively. The problem is over the course of 2 months I can't remember all the changes made and something could come crashing down in the Windows environment and that can't happen even for a short time. I just need some advice.

I was wondering if it's possible to create a clone of `origin master` then push the changes to my local from the prod, merge the files and then upload to the Linux box since I can't push to the Linux now because of the needed pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `git pull`, the changes in the remote `origin` branch are merged into your local `origin` branch.  That is your "local clone of origin/master," so to speak.  Inspect the state of your own master branch, and if everything looks right, then push your changes.

Run `gitk --all` before and after the pull, and you will see that the merge took place, but only on *your* system.

Comment: That makes more sense. I can do that from the developers computer. For some reason I was trying to run the push from the prod server repository itself which doesn't make sense. So if I'm thinking about what you said right, I'll pull into his machine (local) merge and then push to the linux box. I will do this tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Note that `git pull` when you are on master is (usually) equivalent to `git fetch origin master && git merge origin/master`.  If there are any merge conflicts, the merge operation will be interrupted -- then you'll have to deal with the conflicts manually and `git commit` the result.